# How does one swap out spells in Puzzle Quest 2 on the iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ios, puzzle-quest-2

I've been unable to figure out how to swap out spells on puzzle quest 2 for the the ipad/iphone.  I've tried tapping, tapping and holding, dragging and everything else I can think of in the spells menu/listing to change them out but I've been unable to find anything that works.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're already on the spellbook page (by using the spellbook icon in the circles on the bottom left).

To get information on a spell, tap and hold on a spell in your active list (left side) or learned list (right side). To switch them out, tap a spell in the active list once - a single pixel border should appear around the spell slot - then tap a spell in the learned list. The spell slot should be filled with the spell from the right.

This is all way easier to do on an iPad than an iPhone. It seems like the tap version of the game was built for the iPad experience and just scaled down for the iPhone, making all the tap targets extremely small.